# Fetching Result from HTTP Response

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have the following C# class which initiates an HTTP request from a Windows Phone to a server:

```
public class Request
{
    public string data;
    public string result;

    public Request()
    {

    }

    public void doRequest(string parameters, string URL)
    {
        data = parameters;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
    }

    public void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
    }

    public void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

        StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Now, in my main class, I call the doRequest method to do an HTTP request from the Windows Phone:

```
Request req = new Request();
req.doRequest("function=LogIn&username=" + username + "&password=" + password, "http://localhost:4000/Handler.ashx");
```

When calling this method, how can I get the result (the **result variable**) from the server since it is received in the GetResponsetStreamCallback method and not in the doRequest method?

Comment: I don't get your problem... You have subscribed to an event using `IAsynResult` and you handle the event with your method... Get the result in the method `GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)`.

Comment: @bash.d Remember that the large snippet of code is a class of its own.  Whenever I need to use that code, I create an instance of the class and call the doRequest method to make an httpRequest.  The other methods are automatically called by the doRequest method.  However, I don't know how to get the result from this class into the calling class.  Btw, the code in the request class is not mine.  I found it on msdn and modified it a little bit.

Comment: you have 2 choices (perhaps more) make your class implement the same async pattern and allow the users to interact with your call back or  you could make your process blocking and not use begin/end request... when you could then just do it all in one method and return the result.

Comment: I will try your later suggestion.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several possibilities. One would be to define `property` to make the result accessible outside. Define

```
public class Request
{
    public string Result
    {
      get{ 
           if(result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                return result;
           return null;
         }
    }
  ...
}
```

You might create an event and have objects subscribe to it, so you can notice them when the asynchronous request has ended. Or make your calls synchronous, which is a little easier to do, as you don't have synchronize your calls and the requests from other objects.